# Can "foolish" and "folly" be used interchangeably?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning

On StackOverflow, answering a question I introduced a badly written piece of code by saying

> To make it clear, let's have some folly examples.

I wanted to say that the examples the reader is going to see are not sensible and show a lack of good judgment.

I am now having doubts whether *folly* was the right word and whether it conveys the meaning of *foolish*.

My questions are

1. Is my sentence correct?
2. Can *foolish* and *folly* be used interchangeably? If not, provide some examples, please.

**UPDATE**

I discovered *folly* a few months ago in Collins:

> If you say that a particular action or way of behaving is folly [or a folly], you mean that it is foolish.

I missed the part "or a folly". I inaccurately believed *folly* is an adjective (a synonym for *foolish*) and didn't recheck it before asking the difference between those two. My bad, sorry.

Comment: A quick look in the [dictionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/folly) would have shown you that _folly_ is a noun. That said, your update does a good job of explaining how you may have been led to believe otherwise by a credible source. Indeed, _[that] way of behaving is folly_ is a curious construct. Thank you for taking the time to post the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they can't. *Foolish* is an adjective.

*Folly* is a rather literary noun - in everyday English *foolishness* or *stupidity*, or *idiocy* are more common alternatives.

While some nouns can be used as modifiers for other nouns, I can't think of any uses of *folly* as a modifier.

Comment: Yes. Use *foolishness* if you need a corresponding noun. (I would say that's a lighter alternative to *stupidity* or *idiocy*).

Answer (score 1):

> Is my sentence correct? Can foolish and folly be used interchangeably?
>   If not, provide some examples, please.

First, *folly* is a noun, *foolish* is an adjective.

Examples? Here they are (just  a few) , in collocations:

> Pure/ultimate/human follies that you can realize/demonstrate/
>   show, etc.
>
> Foolish act/ mistake/ thing, etc.